# Splitting the voltage from a lipo battery to 5 outputs

Tags: voltage-measurement, lipo

So I'm a bit confused and hopefully I explain my question well.
Let's say I have a LiPo battery at 20v and I need to supply power to 5 different components. My initial thought is just to just create a voltage rail type of thing and have 5 wires coming out of that.

1. Is that a good idea or is there a better way to do this?
2. How do I calculate the voltage and current that would be given to each component?

Below is an idea of my voltage rail. Just a simple wire that expands to 5 other wires to connect to my components.

[image]

Comment: It’s unclear for me what you are proposing. How about adding a schematic?

Comment: Do the components all need different voltages?

Comment: Gonna create a simple schematic quick. And yes, they need different voltages. I was just going to use a buck converter if the voltage was too high

Comment: Your schematic still doesn't make much sense. What are the loads you're going to connect to the battery?

Comment: I added some voltages and currents that my components need.

Comment: You have no closed-path complete-loop "circuit" here so this will not work.   Likely your battery pack is improperly selected.  To realistically do something like this, you would probably use a 2 cell pack and efficient switching regulators, one for each desired output voltage.

Comment: This isn't supposed to be a circuit, is it? I'm just drawing a basic diagram of what I have. I can make something like this https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-xkoep7/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/798/3600/Deans_y_cable_3__43361.1438954218.jpg?c=2 but a 1:5 style.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want, but I would use two switching regulators with a 3V and 5V output.

Comment: I have a lipo battery that I want to use to power my 5 components. How do I calculate how much voltage/current is going to be sent to those components? The voltage/currents I listed are what I NEED. But how does that work? Do they pull as much current as they need? Do they get supplied 4V each since I split it 5 times?

Comment: It might be OK. You would need three regulators. A 5V, a 3V and a 1V. The only issue I can see is that it might be somewhat difficult to source regulators with such high input voltage. SO, you could go in stages. Get one buck to supply 5V, and then get small commodity DC-DC converters to generate 3V and 1V from 5V.

Comment: "Do they pull as much current as they need?" - yes; "Do they get supplied 4V each since I split it 5 times?" - no. If you have a conductor out of the positive terminal that is physically branched into 5, you'll simply get 5 conductors that are 20V with respect to the negative terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This idea is not the original one. In fact, ALL power in notebooks is derived that way, sometimes using a single IC called PMIC, Power Management IC. A typical PMIC also provides a lot other services as PowerGood, all necessary sequencing of power rails, on power on and power down, the necessary suspend sequencing, etc. etc. Some power rails are made as buck converters, some are LDO. The number of rails also varies, 5, 10, 15, whatever is needed for a portable SoC or else. Here is an example: [**NXP PF3001**](https://www.nxp.com/products/power-management/pmics/configurable-pmics-pf-series/10-channel-configurable-pmic:PF3001).